# Firebase @firebase/database PERMISSION_DENIED

Tags: javascript, laravel, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

After successful creating project in `Firebase` and getting configuration form there i pasted this below codes in my code before `</body>`

```js
<script>
    var session_id = "{!! (Session::getId())?Session::getId():'' !!}";
    var user_id = "{!! (Auth::user())?Auth::user()->id:'' !!}";

    var firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "x",
        authDomain: "x",
        databaseURL: "x",
        projectId: "x",
        storageBucket: "x",
        messagingSenderId: "x",
        appId: "x",
        measurementId: "x"
    };

    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

    var database = firebase.database();

    if ({!! auth()->user() !!}) {
        firebase.database().ref('/users/' + user_id + '/session_id').set(session_id);
    }

    firebase.database().ref('/users/' + user_id).on('value', function (snapshot2) {
        var v = snapshot2.val();

        if (v.session_id !== session_id) {

            console.log("Your account login from another device!!");

            setTimeout(function () {
                window.location = '/login';
            }, 4000);
        }
    });
</script>
```

when this page of my application reloded i want to store `session` to `firebase` database, but i get `PERMISSION_DENIED` error, after chceking database inside `firesbase` relaltime database and `/data` tab i have only `XXXX-1c204: null`, i'm not sure why i get this error, because `firebaseConfig` is correct which i multiple check that.

[image]

Error:

> [2020-11-04T04:40:47.932Z]  @firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: set
> at /users/1/session_id failed: permission_denied

`session_id` and `user_id` variables in this section of my code aren't `null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access to the Firebase Realtime Database (and other Firebase backend services) is controlled by [server-side security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security), and it looks like yours are rejecting the write operation to `/users/1/session_id`.

You'll want to modify these rules to allow the minimum that is needed for your application. I recommend thoroughly studying the Firebase documentation on its [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules).